# bitblt replacement for FMX framework

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, msdn

we are using Delphi with VCL framework with the following code snipet

```
  tempBMP := TBitMap.create;

  tempBMP.SetSize(aLargeRectangle.Width, aLargeRectangle.Height);

  BitBlt(tempBMP.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, tempBMP.Width, tempBMP.Height,
     MyOtherImage.Canvas.Handle, aLargeRectangle.Left,
    aLargeRectangle.Top, SRCCOPY)
```

we are now  working on crossplattform programming with these questions

- bitblt is part of gdi32.dll ,  does this mean 32 bit and  only
     good/useable for smaller images ?
- How to use bitblt with FMX
     framework ?
- How to replace bitblt with pure FMX ?  better and
     faster ?

Comment: Since you haven't received any answer yet, let mu just throw in my two cents: If your process is a 64-bit process (which implies that it is running on a 64-bit version of Windows), it will use a 64-bit version of `gdi32.dll`, despite its name. But even if a 32-bit version of GDI is used, you probably wouldn't notice any performance penalty at all if you are using GDI for things GDI is supposed to be used for. I mean, modern 32-bit applications aren't inherently much slower than their 64-bit counterparts. Typically not slower at all.

Comment: (cont.) Since `BitBlt` is a function in the Windows API, it is only available on Windows, of course. You cannot use this function on any other platform, because it doesn't exist on any other platform (unless it is emulated). Personally, I only know the Win32 platform, so I cannot advice you on your cross-platform options, but surely the FMX platform has methods of copying raster image data? I have never touched FMX, but I would be surprised if it had not.

Comment: I might also mention that the GDI system is very old. It dates back to the very first versions of Microsoft Windows in the 80s (!). So although it is robust, has good performance for the tasks it is designed for, and has been extremely well tested over time, it doesn't offer fancy modern graphics capabilities. Microsoft recommends you use Direct2D in new Windows applications. (But again, what you need probably is already offered by the Embarcadero FMX platform, so you don't need to think about Direct2D. Indeed, a direct Direct2D approach would not be cross-platform.)

Comment: I just had a quick look at FMX, and it seems that FMX has the `TCanvas.DrawBitmap` function that you can use. (`Bitmap1.Canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap2, ...);`)